# Error TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, nameerror, nonetype, pyautogui, pynput

I'm trying to write hotkeys in Python using pyautogui and pynput.  I've tried running the code, but I get an the Typeerror: Nonetype is not iterable at what seems to be the execute line.  I've looked at the other questions with similar problems but those solutions don't fix my problem.  What am I missing?  Thanks for your help.

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Listener
import pyautogui
from pyautogui import *


# The key combination to check
COMBINATIONS = [
    pyautogui.hotkey('Cttl', 'shift', 'z')
]

# The currently active modifiers
current = set()


def execute():
    keyboard.KeyCode(char='K'), pyautogui('Ctrl', 's')
    print ("K pressed")


def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute()


def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.remove(key)

with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: I do not quite understand your goal. Are you trying to detect if a certain shortcut was pressed?

Comment: Right now, the print statement is there to just have a terminal response to show it worked.

Comment: updated: I've changed the code but still gets the error.

def execute():
    pyautogui.press('k', 'Ctrl', 'z')
    print ("K pressed and saved")
it errors out at the execute() line when I try to press the hotkey combination.